# style component and useContext not work from nextJs

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components

when denoting useContext and using style-component
passed context disappears

[image]

the value does not change when the button is pressed

[image]

how to properly organize the code to make it work?

```
import { GlobalS } from "../styles/global"
import { Nav } from "../components/nav"
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export const ThemeContext:any = React.createContext({theme: undefined})

export default function Home() {
  const [theme, themeState]:any[] = useState(true)
  async function toggleTheme(){
    themeState(!theme)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(theme)
  }, [theme])
  return (<ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme}}>
  <GlobalS>
    <Nav/>
    <button onClick={()=> toggleTheme()}>toggle</button>
  </GlobalS>
  </ThemeContext.Provider>)
}
```

nav component:

```
import { ThemeContext } from "../pages/index"
import { NavS } from "../styles/nav"

export  const Nav = ():JSX.Element => {
   return (
   <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {(theme:boolean) =>
      <NavS color={theme ? 'black' : 'red'}>
         fu nextjs
      </NavS>}
      
   </ThemeContext.Consumer>)
}
```

nav style:

```
import styled from "styled-components"


export const NavS = styled.nav
`
background: ${(props) => props.color}
`
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? `const [theme, themeState]:any[] = useState(true)`  you provide a boolean state and cast as Array of any. try to remove this so that it automatically infers the type or set explicitly `useState<boolean>(true)`. give it a shot.

Comment: sorry, I misused this hook

Comment: it's okay. you not but the types you misused. so better to avoid wrong types and any type. it's dangerous.